# My Gatsby GraphQL schema wont update with new Sanity schema

Tags: graphql, gatsby, sanity

I am trying to update my CMS to enable a user-defined product slider. Upon adding the relevant schema to my sanity source files (This works) and adding the documents to the schema there is no update on the gatsby side.

I can not find out how to update the graphql schema anywhere. I have tried deleting the cache on both sanity and gatsby, building development versions and trying with them but nothing is working

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whenever your schema changes, you also need to re-deploy you GraphQL endpoints. `cd` to your Studio folder and type:

`sanity graphql deploy`

The Sanity documentation site has more on updating your [GraphQL endpoints](https://www.sanity.io/docs/graphql#deploying-the-graphql-api-04501f1778aa).

Comment: When tryign that command I receive the response " -bash: sanity: command not found"

Answer (score 0):

Use NVM to manage your node versions.

Navigated to the studio folder.

Usually that bash command is associated with NVM not being active or executing the command from a folder where sanity isn't recognized.

Answer (score 0):

For someone who still receives the error "bash: sanity: command not found" after running `sanity graphql deploy`. Use `npx @sanity/cli graphql deploy`.